# Data from the factory when referenced to a scope does not show the value. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new on AngularJS and got stumped on a problem. I'm trying to get a value from a factory and was able to get the data, I attached a console.log() to the function to check, but when I tried to attached these data on a scope and do a check using console.log again, I’m getting a undefined message on the log.

I tried creating an object scope $scope.formWO= {}; and references it there but still I’m getting the same message. I don’t know if there are conflicts between scopes or  an issue of displaying the page early before the system read or perform the function. I already read a lot on scopes but for somehow this problem seem to put my development into a complete stop. I don’t know which is which and would like definitely to get enlightened on this.

Here is the trimmed down controller just to give you an idea.

```
myApp.controller('ordersCtrl', 
    function ordersCtrl($scope, ngTableParams, dealerData, costElementData, totNoData, $http, $ekathuwa, $rootScope, $location, userService, $filter){

    $scope.formWO = {};


        $scope.addWorkOrder = function(){                   

            $scope.modalHeader = "ADD NEW WORK ORDER";
            $scope.modalType = "Add";
            $ekathuwa.modal({
                id: "modalWO",
                scope: $scope,
                templateURL: "./tpl/modal-wo.html"
            });

            $scope.$watch('formWO.dealer', function(newDealer, oldDealer){
                if ( newDealer === oldDealer) {
                    return;
                }

                $http.get('api/profile/'+$scope.formWO.dealer).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config){

                        $scope.formWO.outletno = data.outletno;

                });

                if ($scope.dealer === newDealer) {
                    return;
                }

            }); 

        }

        $scope.submitAddWorkOrder = function(cost_element, desc, ets, etc, cost_estimate, dealer){

            totNoData.getTotNo(function(noData){
                $scope.formWO.totno = noData;
            });

                            console.log($scope.formWO.totno);

            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        }

});
```

Here is the factory:

```
myApp.factory('totNoData', function($http, $log){
    return {
        getTotNo: function(successcb){
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/totno'}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    successcb(data);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is move the log and, I guess, the reload, inside of the anonymous callback function that you're passing to 'getToNo'.  Like:

```
$scope.submitAddWorkOrder = function(cost_element, desc, ets, etc, cost_estimate, dealer){

        totNoData.getTotNo(function(noData){
            $scope.formWO.totno = noData;
            console.log($scope.formWO.totno);
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });
    }
```

As it is, the log and the reload are happening *before* the callback is invoked.  The order would go something like this:

1. call the getTotNo method
2. send the http request
3. step back out to submitAddWorkOrder
4. log $scope.formWO.totno (undefined)
5. call $scope.tableParams.reload();
   ... event loop / digest
6. http response received, success method called
7. callback invoked
8. $scope.formWO.totno is set

Async for the win!

EDIT:

A better to pattern is to return the promise that is returned from the $http call.

So change the service to:

```
getTotNo: function(){
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/totno'});
    }
```

And refactor your controller function to:

```
  $scope.submitAddWorkOrder = function(cost_element, desc, ets, etc, cost_estimate, dealer){

        totNoData.getTotNo().success(function (data) {
            $scope.formWO.totno = noData;
            console.log($scope.formWO.totno);
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
        });
    }
```